# How does VAE generate the value of mean and sd for the latent space?

Tags: autoencoders

I am just trying to understand the detailed mechanisms of VAE (variational autoencoder), and even new to Deep Learning.
I was wondering, how does the encoder part of the VAE can make sure to generate the value of Gaussian mean and sd?
I checked the code from Keras, it seems they used the same function to generate this two values? Then how do you know which is which?
[image]
Thanks for any replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`layers.Dense` is a dense layer. The code uses a different dense layer for each of the mean and the log-standard deviation. We know that it uses a different dense layer for each because  `layers.Dense` instantiates a new dense layer object, and that class is used twice.

You're right, there's nothing about this network that mandates that one *must* be the mean (except for the fact of how they're used). The one that you use for the mean is the mean; the one that you use for the standard deviation is the standard deviation. The advantage to working with log-standard deviation in this model is that you don't have to worry about the non-negativity constraint on the standard deviation because logs of positive numbers are real.